# SQL datetime performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, datetime

The query below runs perfectly without dateVon2 and dateBis2 but if I add these two columns in the WHERE clause it takes very long to execute.

How can I speed up this query?

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE dateVon1>= CAST('01.01.2014 00:00.000' AS DATETIME) 
AND dateBis1< (CAST('10.11.2015 00:00.000' AS DATETIME)+1)
AND dateVon2>= CAST('01.01.2014 00:00.000' AS DATETIME) 
AND dateBis2 < (CAST('10.11.2019 00:00.000' AS DATETIME)+1)
```

Comment: Store dates as dates, and index them. And don't use 'SELECT *'. But what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Something that I can make up for :  
First: make sure you have a relevant index on that column. Secondly: don't use any functions (like CAST) on your datetime columns in WHERE expressions.

Comment: I'm not understanding how the expression `CAST('01.01.2014 00:00.000' AS DATETIME)` can return anything except `NULL`. I'm puzzled how this query, either with or without predicates on the `dateVon2` and `dateBis2` columns) can return more than zero rows. I'm having difficulty reconciling the query text provided in the question with the reported behavior: it "runs perfectly".

Answer (score 1):

Don't use CAST.

Do state dates in the native format:  `'2014/01/01'`.

Don't use `+1`.  Do this instead:  `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

But...  The `WHERE` clause cannot be made very efficient.  Tests on "intervals" are difficult.  About the best you can do is:

```
INDEX(dateVon1) -- adding more columns won't help

WHERE dateVon1 >= '2014/01/01'
  AND ...
```